# Problemas con el json en android

Tags: android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema a la hora de dar de alta a un usuario en mi app de android

En el registro.java tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public class Registrarse extends AppCompatActivity  {
    EditText etnombre, etusuario, etpassword, etedad;
    Button btn_registrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrarse);

        etnombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Registro_nombre);
        etusuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Registro_usuario);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Registro_pass);
        etedad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Registro_edad);

        btn_registrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.R_rgr);
        btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = etnombre.getText().toString();
                String username = etusuario.getText().toString();
                String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
                int edad = Integer.parseInt(etedad.getText().toString());

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success)
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Registrarse.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                Toast.makeText(Registrarse.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registrarse.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegistroRequest registroRequest = new RegistroRequest(name, edad ,username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registrarse.this);
                queue.add(registroRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

En el registro request.java tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class RegistroRequest extends StringRequest{

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="http://172.20.23.65/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegistroRequest(String name,  int age, String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name",name);
        params.put("edad", age+"");
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
```

Y mi código php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");

    $name = $_POST["name"];   
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  


    echo json_encode($response);
```

El fallo que me da es el siguiente:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value `<br` of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Así a simple vista te diría que a esta linea: JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response); le estas pasando un response que al conversor de JSON no le gusta. Te diría que pusieras un breakpoint y debugearas hasta ese punto para ver el valor de la variable "response".

Comment: @DavidRománRey primero asegura tu respuesta es en verdad json, el problema es precisamente que no es este tipo de respuesta. Probablemente es un error, asegura que tu .php obtenga el .json.

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: age in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
{"succes":true} eso es lo que me sale @Corpex

Comment: Vamos, que como dice @Jorgesys no te esta devolviendo un archivo json, y por tanto da error al intentar convertirlo.

Comment: @Corpex eso es cuando hago el debug el valor le pasa un <br

Comment: @DavidRománRey imprime el valor de response

Comment: @Jorgesys <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: age in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
{"succes":true}

Comment: @DavidRománRey es un error en el .php, debes corregirlo :(

Comment: @Jorgesys <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];   
    $age = $_POST["age"];
 $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    
    $response = array();
    $response["succes"] = true;  
    
    echo json_encode($response);
?>

Comment: David, si el código PHP funciona como debería no tiene por qué haber problema. Ahora bien, **debes indicar en PHP que el código devuelve un JSON y además debes especificar una codificación adecuada**, para evitar malas jugadas con caracteres extraños. Esto puedes hacerlo poniendo lo siguiente antes del `echo`...: **`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`** De todos modos, tu código no es real, estableces un valor a `true` de forma arbitraria, el valor que devuelvas debería depender del número de filas afectadas en el insert, pues en algunos casos éste puede no ocurrir.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que realiza tu código es obtener la respuesta y tratar de convertirla a un `JSONObject` :

```
          @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    ... 
                    ...
```

El problema aquí es que la respuesta no es propia de contenido JSON y no es un objeto JSON, ya que debe iniciar con  `{`.

Si la respuesta no es un JSON obtendrás el error:

> System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value `<br` of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject

de hecho si revisas el error, en realidad estas obteniendo contenido html (`<br`).